# What is wrong with this mysqldump command?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run the following mysqldump command through a python shell. Please, just don't bother asking why I'm doing this through python. This simple code is just for demonstration sake.

```
import os
import time

user = 'the_user'
password = 'the_password'
host = 'my_host'
database = 'the_db'

filestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 os.popen("mysqldump -u %s -p%s -h %s --opt -c %s | gzip -c > %s.gz" % (user,password,host,database,database+"_"+filestamp))
```

However, I am getting a weird error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
>   'the_user'@'my_isp_wtf?' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

It's telling me that access is denied for the user@host, but it's using a host that I did not specify. I am not sure if it's telling me I'm not whitelisted from my IP, or if it's trying to connect to an incorrect host?

Comment: Can you dump out the resulting string you build and pass to os.popen? If that is correct, can you execute it like it is and it works outside of Python? I know you are obfuscating the info you are using with strings like 'my_hosy', but are those IP addresses, URLs, etc.?

Comment: Yes, it is telling you that your ip (the ip you are running that command from) is not whitelisted. Better execute mysqldump on the server mysql is running at.